# XAML WPF Style Triggers for Property Changes

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

This is a two part question. I am trying to play around with WPF Style Triggers.

1) I have a Rectangle that should change color based on the image source of imgIcon (the icon can only have 3 possible outcomes, a) checkbox.png -> green rectangle b) cancel.png -> red rectangle c) pending.png -> orange rectangle. I was able to create the style, but cannot figure out how to reference the source of the image.

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFAF504B" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Rectangle>
 <Image x:Name="imgIcon" Source="Images/cancel.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="30"/>
```

2) I have a small box called bxCredit. Box has text labels inside. When the label called bxCreditPeriod is greater than 0 (or not null), it should show the entire box (other wise hide). Now this i know can't be done with a trigger, but I am looking to figure out how to hide the entire content based on a property of bxCreditPeriod. Is it possible? and if so how?

```
    <Border x:Name="bxCredit" CornerRadius="5">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Opacity=".8"/>
        </Border.Effect>    
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="35" Height="30" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <Rectangle Height="10" Fill="Gainsboro" VerticalAlignment="TOP"/>
            <Label Content="EXPORT" FontSize="7" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label x:Name="bxCreditPeriod" Content="var" FontSize="18" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="23"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

This must be pretty simple, but I have no idea where to begin!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this sample [project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140623/WPF-Tutorial-Styles-Triggers-Animation)